# Is there a way to connect a specific Discord.js client to a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a distributed music-playing bot for a single guild/server. This involves a single bot taking in commands from the server members and assigning "loudspeaker" bots to their channels. I currently have a working Discord.js v14 bot that is equipped with doing other things. In its index.html page, I'm able to log in several other "loudspeaker" bot clients after I log in the main bot, and that works fine (the loudspeakers show up as online in the user list).

In an ideal world, I'd like to be able to make a specific bot join a voice channel with `loudspeakerClient.voice.join(voiceChannel);` or something and have it play music, but that simple of a solution doesn't seem to exist. According to [their official voice guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#cheat-sheet), I have to create a connection and an adapter. Doing the function listed at the top of the page (with a few edits to fit my code)

```
const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: channel.id,
      guildId: channel.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
});
```

causes the main bot to connect to the voice channel. There's no [option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/main/typedef/JoinVoiceChannelOptions) to select what client to connect through this method. Is there any way to specify a client when performing this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears the 'voiceAdapterCreator' is a thing defined by the client that the discord/voice modules uses to connect to channels.

In this case, you'd want to additionally fetch the guild using whichever client you want to join...

*Let's say there's clientMain, clientA, clientB, etc... and the clients are mapped via a simple obj called 'clientMap': {channelMainId: clientMain, channelAId: clientA, etc...}:*

```js
var thisClient = clientMap[interaction.member.voice.channel.id]
var channel = await thisClient.channels.fetch(channel.id) // Make sure you add the 'async' keyword to the function
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: channel.id,
      guildId: channel.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator // Should be referring to the correct client
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I also asked this question on the D.JS Discord server and this seems to be the case. I have yet to try it but I will update when I do, thanks!

Here's a link to the help I got: https://discord.com/channels/222078108977594368/1090014703209693194/1090123144594980934